# namespace`ы autoload composer . Не могу разобраться , не могу создать экземпляр класса

Tags: php, ооп, composer, autoload

Есть веб сайт , структура файлов такая
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код из UsersController.php

```
namespace app\controllers;


use \app\Models\UsersModel;
class UsersController
{
        public function signUP()
        {
           $test2 = new UsersModel();
           $test2->sign();


        }



}
```

код из UsersModel.php

```
namespace app\Models;

use app\controllers\UsersController;

class UsersModel
{
    public function sign()
    {
        echo "я в модели";
    }
}
```

index.php

```
require_once __DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php";



require_once __DIR__."/router/routes.php";
```

composer.json

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4":{
        "app\\": "app"

    }
  }
}
```

Я хочу в контроллере вызвать метод sign в классе модели , но у меня ошибка
"Uncaught Error: Class 'app\Models\UsersModel' not found in F:\OSPanel\domains\AuthOOP\app\controllers\UsersController.php:18"
не пойму что не так , вроде и автозагрузчик есть , вроде IDE подсвечивает что все нормально , но ошибка все равно . Я недавно начал изучать ООП и первый раз столкнулся с автозагрузчиком класса , так что не очень понимаю , но хочу разобраться . Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `require_once __DIR__."/router/routes.php";` --- вот это вроде бы не нужно....... достаточно вендор автолоад........вместо `use \app\Models\UsersModel;` попробуй `use app\Models\UsersModel;`   то есть без обратной черты в начале

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , убрал обратную черту , все равно ошибка.

Comment: ради интереса удали папку vendor и сделай composer install   (слэш обратно не возвращай и routes не подключай)

Comment: Удалил , прописал composer install , снова создалась папка vendor и composer.lock . Ошибка осталась . может я как-то не так прикрепляю его , но тогда я не пойму куда нужно . В моем понимании Inex.php загружается и подгружает сразу автозагрузчик , но почему-то мой контроллер не хочет видеть класс модели :(

Comment: да, после composer install должны были записаться данные в файлы загрузчика и строчки `require_once __DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php";`  хватило бы...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ,  сейчася прописал в контроллере require_once "../../vendor/autoload.php"; и он начал видеть класс модели , ошибка пропала.  Но тогда объясните почему в Index.php он не работал , а когда я его подключил в контроллере он работает О_о Как это работает , как он теперь видит классы . Я запутался , но если подключить автозагрузчик в контроллере то все нормально отрабатывает и классы видят друг друга )

Comment: один момент... хочу на будущее сказать: ЕМНИП (может кто поправит меня), всякий раз когда будут добавляться новые классы, придётся делать composer update, чтобы инфа в файлах автолоада обновлялась....... я сделал когда то проще я прописал `{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/",
            "config/"
        ]
    }
}`.....  по поводу пути в контроллере ничего не могу сказать, возможно у тебя не работало в index.php потому что ты открывал URL  типа `myhost/UsersController.php`  а должен был `myhost/index.php`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, На счет composer update не знал ) спасибо . Да , у меня прописан то в индексе автозагрузка , а я находился на странице регистрации ( register.php ) , может как-то из-за этого классы не видели друг друга) 
Я думал что если вначале будет открываться Index.php , а потом я буду переходить на страницу регистрации то автозагрузка будет все равно отрабатывать , но видно я ошибался .

Comment: конечно ошибался... так это не работает.... раз все классы подключаются в index.php то и работа вся должна происходить через этот самый файл....просто register ничего не знает про index... а сервер всю работу ведёт через тот файл, который указан в URL.... Поэтому обычно делают **маршрутизацию**, чтобы все запросы шли на index файл, а тот уже рулил что куда посылать